# Issue with saving edited notes in modal form

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently facing an issue with saving edited notes in a modal form on my website. I have a modal that allows users to edit their notes, but when they click "Save changes," the updated note is not being saved correctly. It saves it as null. the note is then empty the desired edits did not save in the DB

Here's the structure of my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="noteModal">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Notes</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                           
                                            <div class="modal-body">

                                            
            <form id="editNoteForm" action="#" method="POST" >
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
              
                
                <textarea name="note_content" id="noteContent" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control bg-transparent" title="Please edit your note" required> </textarea>
            </form>
                              
     

                                            </div>
                                         <form id="saveEditsForm"  action="#" method="POST">
                                            @method('PUT')
                                            @csrf




                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </form>

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

here is the code in my controller

```
   // the following function is to edit a note
     public function editNote($note_id) {
    $note = notes::find($note_id);
    return response()->json([
        'noteContent' => $note->note
    ]);
}

  public function editNoteForm($note_id)
{
   $note = notes::find($note_id);

if (!$note) {
    // Handle the case when the note is not found
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Note not found!');
}

return view('modal') -> with ('note',$note);
}

 public function saveEdits(Request $request, $note_id)
 {
    $noteContent = $request->input('note_content');

$note = notes::find($note_id);

if (!$note) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Note not found!');
  }

     $note->note = $noteContent;
$note->save();

return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Note updated successfully.');
```

my route

```
Route::get('edit-note/{note_id}', [NotesController::class, 'editNoteForm'])->name('edit-note-form');


 Route::put('save-edits/{note_id}', [NotesController::class, 'saveEdits']) -> name('saveEdits');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your 'note_content[]' field is not inside the 'saveEditsForm' form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have this:

```
@foreach ($notes as $note)
    <input type="hidden" name="note_content[]" value="{{ $note->note }}">
@endforeach
<form id="saveEditsForm"  action="{{ route('saveEdits', ['note_id' => $note->note_id]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

But your note info it´s out of `form` and you have other form higher. I don´t understan very well why you ar using hidden input to update notes. if you want that user edit this notes, maybe you can use:

```
<form id="saveEditsForm"  action="{{ route('saveEdits', ['note_id' => $note->note_id]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

    <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
       @foreach ($notes as $note)
         {{ $note->note }}"
       @endforeach
    </textarea>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I add more code to give a better idea.
 the i have two form on the modal because editnoteform is to pull the existing not from the db and display it on the textarea so you can make an fix and then a second form called savededits form is to save the updated not to the db with the same id